# How many numbers equal $6$?

Tags: inequality

let $-6\le x_{i}\le 10,i=1,2,3,\cdots,10$,and such 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_{i}=50$$
when the maximum
 $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{10}x^2_{i}$ ,if and only if $x_{i}$  $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{10}$ ,
How many numbers $x_{i}$ is equal $6$,

$A:1 $

$B:2$

$C:3$

$D:4$

My solution:let $x_{i} $ equal $6$ have $n$ numbers,then we have
$$-6n+10(10-n)\ge 50$$
$$\Longrightarrow n\le\dfrac{50}{16}$$
so $n=3,2,1$

on the other hand, $10,10,10,10,10,10,-6,-6,-6,8$
such $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}x^2_{i}$$ is maximum .

my solution is true? I feel somewrong How prove $\sum_{i=1}^{10}x^2_{i}$ is maximum?

Comment: is this a homework?

Comment: Hello,No,It's  2012 china Mathematical olympiad comption problem

Comment: You can have nine sixes, but with a poor sum of squares.  Maybe it was asking for the minimum sum of squares?

Comment: As this is a quadratic problem, whose unconstrained maximum is unbounded, you must have all variables at the boundaries at the constrained maximum, so the only way you can get a $6$ is if other variables are all $\in \{10, -6\}$ and $6$ is needed to satisfy the sum constraint.  For that to happen, your constraint needs to be the sum is $48$.  Perhaps they were asking how many variables are at $-6$?

Comment: Does the problem ask how many $x_i$ equal $6$ or does it ask how many $x_i$ equal $-6$?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem asked for number of $x_i$ equal to $-6$. First note that you can't have more than one internal numbers, that is, $x_i>-6$ and $x_i<10$ because in that case, you can change one of them to $-6$ or $10$ and adjust the other to keep sum unchanged while increasing $\sum x_i^2$. Second, there is no combination of only $-6$s and $10$s that sums to $50$. So the solution must have $k$ instances of $10$, $(9-k)$ instances of $-6$ and one more internal number, say $y$ such that the sum equals $50$. So $y=104-16k$. The only value of $k$ for which $y>-6$ and $y<10$ is $k=6$ so there have to be $3$ instances of $-6$.